# Problems jumping from root tab to root tab

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ion-nav

Which is the best way for doing this?

[image: Tabs Screens]

I have three options, but I do not like any of them.

**Option 1:**

- TabsPage 2: Create “A, B, C” like a “Footer”
- Disable subpage Tabs in config opcion (take out Tabs “1, 2, 3”)
- GO: Use “NavBar Push(Screen2)”.
- BACK: “NavBar pop()”

**Problems:**

1. Create tab “A, B, C” with “Footer” instead of “ion-tab”

**Option 2:**

- Use “Modal Form” for “screen2”.
- TabsPage 2:

  - Create “A, B, C” like a “Footer”
  - Create manually “back button”
- GO: View Modal
- BACK: Dismiss modal

**Problems:**

1. Create tab “A, B, C” with “Footer” instead of “ion-tab”
2. back button is not automatically generated.

**Option 3:**

- Create two “TabsPage” with “ion-tabs” for “1, 2, 3” and for “A, B, C”.
- GO: this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage2)
- BACK: this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage1)

**Problems:**

1. “TabsPage 1” filter options and position is lost when “BACK”.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/99-cant-solve-this-creating-two-tab-pages-in-ionic-ion-tabs/118477/8) drived me to this [github repo](https://github.com/Jacktoolsnet/01_TabsPage) which has an example with a solutions based on "ion-tab" that works for both "Modals" and "Push" (see the example on a [video](https://youtu.be/3htl7iWoZsY)).

The problem is solved just by adding *[tabsHideOnSubPages]="true"* on TabsPage1, like this:

```html
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [tabsHideOnSubPages]="true" [root]="homePage" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="chatPage" tabIcon="chatbubbles"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="profilePage" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I have used "push" just because like that the "back" button is generated automatically.

Great!
J. Pablo.